# ASP.net MVC timeout issue with Button Control

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I have a simple asp.net mvc application with some dev controls. Main screen has a button that takes date from screen and does back end processing. 
VIEW:

```
@Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
                {
                    settings.Name = "LoadData";
                    settings.Text = "Load Data";
                    settings.ToolTip = "Imports data from Holding API"; 
                    settings.ClientSideEvents.Click = "OnClick";
                    settings.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
                }).GetHtml()
```

```
 function OnClick(s, e) {
        positionDate = ReportingPositionDate.GetDate().toDateString();
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //url: "/ImportData/DataFileUpload",
            url: "@Url.Action("DataFileUpload", "ImportData")",
            data: JSON.stringify({ positionDate: positionDate }),
            dataType: "text",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            beforeSend: function () { lpImport.Show(); },
            success: function (msg)
            {
                ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
                ImportSuccessMessage.SetVisible(true);
                ImportSuccessMessage.SetText(msg);
                lpImport.Hide();
            },
            Error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr)
                ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DataFileUpload(string positionDate)
{
    // Reset validation error collection
    ImportDataValidationErrors = new List<ImportFileRecord>();
    string[] errs;
    try
    {
        ReturnVal ="Some Long Running Process"
        return Content(ReturnVal);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Process takes about 50 minutes (or more) to run (expected). Controller method DataFileUpload does all actions correctly when it comes to returning to View, it just hangs up. My guess is that my screen has timed out and not accepting any response from the controller. 
When I run same process with smaller dataset, view get value back from Controller. Any idea what could be going wrong here? Any issue with my button settings ? 
Appreciate all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery Ajax default timeout value is 0. This means no timeout in ajax. If the browser has some timeout it's entirely possible you'll hit that.

Only when a timeout option is specified does jQuery even call setTimeout().

Also there is another challenge. There is browser timeout for ajax (XMLHttpRequest), its different for each browser especially for IE. I guess its 30 min or so.
Technically you can set `timeout : 10000000` its between 2.30~3 hours.

I faced this problem before. You can solve with progress bar. With progress bar you can keep refreshed your view.

For simple ajax request that you can use.

```
function uploadFile(){
    myApp.showProgressDialog; //show dialog
    var file=document.getElementById('fileName').files[0];
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file_name", file);
    ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", ProgressBarHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", OnCompleteHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "/to/action");
    ajax.send(formData);
}

function ProgressBarHandler(event){
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    $('.bar').width(percent); // its coming from css
}

function OnCompleteHandler(){
    myApp.hidePleaseWait(); //hide dialog
    $('.bar').width(100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Orhun. I will try your recommendation. For timeout, are you saying I can use something like:  

$.ajax({
              // existing
                Error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr)
                    ImportDataGridView.PerformCallback();
                },
                timeout : 10000000
            })
 ?

Comment: Yes! You can use but there is browser timeout, like before you face it, IE is real problem but please consider following sentence. Best practice to solve this is progress bar. I deeply recommend progress bar with long pooling :) good luck with that. After that please share your test result.